# Divide data frame by vector, by rows and not by columns

Tags: r

I have this data frame and vector that I want to divide the rows with:

```
div <- c(10,100,1000)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1,9),nrow=3))
df <- cbind(type = as.factor(c("A","B","C")),df)
> df
  type V1 V2 V3
1    A  1  1  1
2    B  1  1  1
3    C  1  1  1
```

I would like the answer in data frame form, with the factors to remain as they are.
When dividing it with the vector, I get the "wrong" answer:

```
df1 <- cbind(df[,1], df[,-1]/div)
> df1
  df[, 1]    V1    V2    V3
1       A 0.100 0.100 0.100
2       B 0.010 0.010 0.010
3       C 0.001 0.001 0.001
```

I want each row divided by the vector, not each column.

My workaround was this:

```
divfun <- function(x){
  x / div
}

df2 <- cbind(df[,1], t(apply(df[,-1], 1, divfun)))
> df2
        V1   V2    V3
[1,] 1 0.1 0.01 0.001
[2,] 2 0.1 0.01 0.001
[3,] 3 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

Notice that the factors are now lost.

So two questions here:

1. Is there a more simple way to do it, without making a new function for it?
2. Assuming there is no simpler way, what happened to my factors A, B and C? I'm guessing that it has something to do with coercing to matrix (because of the `t()`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the transpose function:

```
> df[,2:4] <- t(t(df[,2:4]) / div)
> df
  type  V1   V2    V3
1    A 0.1 0.01 0.001
2    B 0.1 0.01 0.001
3    C 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

Comment: Actually I tried something like that, but I did a double transpose on the vector, not the data frame. It didn't occur to me that I could/should.

Answer (score 7):

The function you are looking for is `sweep()`:

```
sweep(df[, -1], MARGIN = 2, div, FUN = "/")

> sweep(df[, -1], MARGIN = 2, div, FUN = "/")
   V1   V2    V3
1 0.1 0.01 0.001
2 0.1 0.01 0.001
3 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

Hence

```
cbind(type = df[,1], sweep(df[, -1], 2, div, FUN = "/"))

> cbind(type = df[,1], sweep(df[, -1], 2, div, FUN = "/"))
  type  V1   V2    V3
1    A 0.1 0.01 0.001
2    B 0.1 0.01 0.001
3    C 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

gets you the desired output.

Note that here, the argument `MARGIN` doesn't refer to the rows (`1`) or columns (`2`) like it does in `apply()`. In `sweep()` it refers to the margin(s) of the array that correspond to `STATS`, the vector you wish to sweep out (of divide by in this case). In other words, the first element of `STATS` (`div` in your case) is the value to sweep out of column 1, the second element of `STATS` is the value to sweep out of column 2, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

```
df[,-1] <- df[,-1]/div[col(df)]
 df
#  type  V1   V2    V3
#1    A 0.1 0.01 0.001
#2    B 0.1 0.01 0.001
#3    C 0.1 0.01 0.001

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ type: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
# $ V1  : num  0.1 0.1 0.1
# $ V2  : num  0.01 0.01 0.01
# $ V3  : num  0.001 0.001 0.001
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(454)
 dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(200, 1e3*1e2, replace=TRUE), ncol=1e2))
 set.seed(29)
 div <- sample(40, 1e2, replace=TRUE)


 f1 <- function() {sweep(dat, MARGIN = 2, div, FUN = "/")}
 f2 <- function() {t(t(dat) / div)}
 f3 <- function() { mapply("/", dat, div)}
 f4 <- function() {dat/div[col(dat)]}
 f5 <- function() {for(r in 1:nrow(dat)){    
             dat[r,]/div}}

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), unit="relative")
 #Unit: relative
 # expr         min          lq      median          uq        max neval
 # f1()    6.765024    6.724991    6.434463    5.124457   10.91735   100
 # f2()    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.00000   100
 # f3()   18.028441   18.551529   16.742279   14.239107   13.72168   100
 # f4()    6.315330    6.577099    6.333656    5.052068   10.13038   100
 # f5() 4211.839669 3908.555985 3945.130154 2962.534518 1655.12268   100
```

Comment: Nice information in the benchmarking. However, does the fact that I may have a column (or more) of factors in the data frame, similar to the question, affect any of the benchmarks? The algorithm has to first subset the numbers out of the original data frame.

Comment: @Michael  I don't think it will have much effect.  Even if it has, it should reflect in all the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Or try `mapply`

```
cbind(df[, 1], mapply("/", df[, -1], div))

##        V1   V2    V3
## [1,] 1 0.1 0.01 0.001
## [2,] 2 0.1 0.01 0.001
## [3,] 3 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

Comment: I'd be interested to note the relative speediness of `mapply` vs `sweep` in this instance (well on larger problems). `mapply` seems more natural given the binary operator `/` and `sweep` has this curious notion of a `MARGIN` that I always fail to get right on first use. That said, I'm old school and `sweep` was the tool of choice then and it was so because it was *fast*. Anyone care to do some timings on larger problems? (I would but I'm off to a seminar now...)

Comment: Actually the OP wants to know *why* `type` gets converted and would like to preserve the factor variable. The output they show is as far as their workaround got. Hence this gives not quite the desired result.

Comment: Gavin is right. I want to preserve the factors.

Answer (score 2):

I like David's solution but I would modify it to convert it to a data frame since that keeps the factor instead of getting a matrix.

```
data.frame(type=df[, 1], mapply("/", df[, -1], div))

#  type  V1   V2    V3
#1    A 0.1 0.01 0.001
#2    B 0.1 0.01 0.001
#3    C 0.1 0.01 0.001
```

which is what I would like to get.

Comment: The OP's desired output was a matrix though...

Comment: You can just do `cbind.data.frame()` instead (or `type=df[, 1, drop = FALSE]` should work as well as S3 dispatch would kick in).

Comment: David, actually what I wanted is a data frame with the factors remain intact. I edited my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
for(r in 1:nrow(df))    
    df[r,2:4]= df[r,2:4]/div
df
  type  V1   V2    V3
1    A 0.1 0.01 0.001
2    B 0.1 0.01 0.001
3    C 0.1 0.01 0.001
```